# Is there a Google Drive API that allows you to navigate through the file system?

Tags: javascript, html, google-drive-api, drive

I am looking through the Google Cloud API forums and was trying to find if there is a way to use/edit the search bar for navigation.

**Objective -** 
I am trying to do is implement Google Drive into my website. People will be allowed to open a bunch of videos in the drive through a bunch of folders.

Of course it would not be an inconvenience to navigate through the folders so using search would be ideal. But the problem is when you type, "Stars" it only shows the results in your own drive, not the (**websites owners drive.**) Of course you can get around it by typing **(file:owner)** then the word" but this would not be a good idea sense some people do not read/understand it. Is there a way that I could auto-fill in the first part of the search bar with **(file:owner)** with code? Or a API in the Drive Framework that will help me edit the search bar? Thank you for the help if you give any.

Comment: Try this [manage team drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-teamdrives) option from the documentation. You will be able to manage members and permission across the organization using the specific team drive.

Comment: Could I make it so when a person types a keyword in the search bar it will display the video without typing file:owner?